# problems when I call a WCF webservice from AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, wcf, web-services

I have a Web Application.In this application I add an AJAX enabled WCF service .The calss name is PricingService and the code is below:

```
namespace PricingService
{
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "PricingService")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class PricingService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke]
    public double CalculatePrice(string itemId, string shipToPostalCode)
    {
        double price;
        price = 45;
        price = price * 1.06;
        return price;

    }

}
}
```

I want to call this service from AJAX ,from a web site in ASP.net.
In default.aspx page I add this code:

```
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="http://localhost:49340/PricingService.svc" />
    </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    Product: <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    Ship to (Postal code ):<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="ButtonCalculate" type="button" value="Get Price" onclick="buttonCalculate_onClick()"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="LabelPrice" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>


</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function buttonCalculate_onClick() {
        var service = new PricingService.PricingService();
        service.CalculatePrice(document.form[0].txtProduct.value,document.form[0].txtPostCode.value,onSucces,onFail,null);

    }

    function onSuccess(result) {
        LabelPrice.innerText = result;
    }

    function onFail(result) {
        alert(result);
    }

</script>
</form>
</body>
```

When i click the button i receive the message : The 'PricingService' is undefined
Can somebody tell me what's the problem?
The web site and wcf service are in the same project called 'WcfServiceApplication'
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The guys over at Microsoft have some very good documentation.  Instead of regergitating all their stuff I'll just point you in the right direction.
[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514961%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) shows you how to setup your service. The next article down will show you how to consume it.
Hope this helps.